# Apt-Get Update Failed to fetch; Unable to connect

Tags: apt

On Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
when attempting to run apt-get update, I get this:

```
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports InRelease

Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease

Err http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release.gpg
  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/InRelease

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to us.archive.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to security.ubuntu.com:http: [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've been able to successfully apt-get update and upgrade on this machine in the past. I'm not sure what changed. I can ping the addresses just fine. I'm using 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for DNS. I'm not using a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

check the following cases:

1. check your internet connection.
2. ping any website (www.google.com),it will help you the packets are received or not.
3. check any proxy is set or not.
4. check any website in browsers (chrome/firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Do `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, and see if the output has something like this:

```
# [network]
# generateResolvConf = false
nameserver 172.X.X.X
```

You'll need to change the nameserver to `8.8.8.8`, so run `sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf`, edit and save the file.

Try running `sudo apt update` afterwards and see if it works.